# Как создать сложный словарь?

Tags: python

Есть данные, которые приходят с html формы:

```
camId = request.form.getlist('id') #список id кампаний
camName = request.form.getlist('campaign_name') # список имён кампаний
maxBid = request.form.getlist('maxbid') # список максимальных ставок для кампании
status = request.form.getlist('status') # список статусов 'on'\'off'
client = request.form['client'] # логин клиента
```

Все списки имеют одинаковую длину.
Подскажите, как из имеющихся данных создать такую структуру:

```
{client:{'Campaigns':{'id':12345, 'name':'poisk', 'maxbid':50, 'status':'on'},{'id':54321, 'name':'poisk2', 'maxbid':60, 'status':'on'},...}}
```

Comment: Так и создать. В чём Вы видите проблему? Это валидная структура.

Comment: Не вижу смысла в квадратных скобках, зачем создавать список из одного элемента?

Comment: @V-Mor Campaign**s**, недвусмысленно намекает. Хотя тут скорее имелось в виду Companies :)

Comment: Если список статусов короче остальных, как узнать, какой статус относится к какой компании? Например, есть `[компания1, компания2, компания3]` и `[статус1, статус2]`. Как сопоставить?

Comment: И куда в нужном словаре деть номер клиента?

Comment: Дайте пример: `camId camName maxBid status client` А то взаимосвязь - не очевидна.

Comment: @extrn Точно! Недоглядел, простите мою глупость.

Comment: @extrn  campaigns и companies разные слова, в данном случае имеются ввиду рекламные кАмпании :)

Comment: @V-Mor ок, дабы не морочится лишнего, все списки будут одинаковой длины. Номер клиента тут не фигурирует , только логин : {'логин клиента':{'Campaigns':{

Comment: @ВикторСмольский это я и имел в виду, просто не подумал, что что речь могла на самом деле идти о кампаниях.

Comment: @ВикторСмольский Тогда смотрите мой ответ. Как раз для такой ситуации расписал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если статусов не меньше, чем всех остальных элементов списков, можно сделать так:

```py
camId = request.form.getlist('id') #список id кампаний
camName = request.form.getlist('campaign_name') # список имён кампаний
maxBid = request.form.getlist('maxbid') # список максимальных ставок для кампании
status = request.form.getlist('status') # список статусов 'on'\'off'
client = request.form['client'] # логин клиента

result = {}
result[client] = {}
result[client]["Campagins"] = []  

for i in range(len(camId)):
    result[client]["campagins"].append({'id':camId[i], 'name':camName[i], 'maxbid':maxBid[i], 'status':status[i]})    

print(result)
```

Реализация наивная, возможно (и скорее всего), можно сделать лучше.

Если же, всё-таки, статусов меньше, этот код завершится ошибкой. Чтобы этого избежать, необходимо либо передавать пустые статусы, либо знать правило сопоставления определённой компании с определённым статусом (как я и писал в комментариях).

Comment: Сердечное спасибо! Помогло. Проще сделать список статусов одинаковой длины, что и другие списки , чем потом сопоставлять их с кампаниями :)

Comment: @ВикторСмольский Всегда рад помочь

Answer (score 1):

```
from pprint import pprint as print

client = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']
camId = [1, 2, 3, 4]
camName = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B']
maxBid = [10, 20, 30, 40]
status = [100, 200, 300, 40]

result = {}
for i in zip(client, camId, camName, maxBid, status):
    data = {'id': i[1], 'name': i[2], 'maxbid': i[3], 'status': i[4]}
    if i[0] not in result.keys():
        result[i[0]] = {}
    if 'Campaigns' not in result[i[0]].keys():
        result[i[0]]['Campaigns'] = []
    result[i[0]]['Campaigns'].append(data)

print(result)
```

Вариант с `try except`:

```
from pprint import pprint as print

client = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']
camId = [1, 2, 3, 4]
camName = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B']
maxBid = [10, 20, 30, 40]
status = [100, 200, 300, 40]

result = {}
for i in zip(client, camId, camName, maxBid, status):
    data = {'id': i[1], 'name': i[2], 'maxbid': i[3], 'status': i[4]}
    try:
        result[i[0]]['Campaigns'].append(data)
    except KeyError:
        result[i[0]] = {'Campaigns': [data]}

print(result)
```

Результат:

```
{'a': {'Campaigns': [{'id': 1, 'maxbid': 10, 'name': 'A', 'status': 100}]},
 'b': {'Campaigns': [{'id': 2, 'maxbid': 20, 'name': 'B', 'status': 200},
                     {'id': 4, 'maxbid': 40, 'name': 'B', 'status': 40}]},
 'c': {'Campaigns': [{'id': 3, 'maxbid': 30, 'name': 'C', 'status': 300}]}}
```